# Assign multiple outputs to multiple variables and use them as inputs, once per task of another program in batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, variables, cmd

I have 2 programs say temperature and weekday

Weekday outputs a day in a week from a file, the result could be Monday -> Friday

```
weekday *.*
```

Temperature outputs the temperature of a day in a week

```
temperature day
```

I'm trying to create a batch file that uses `weekday` to extract multiple outputs from multiple files and use a pipe to redirect those outputs to the inputs of `temperature` by variables.

This is the batch I created

```
for %%I in ("*.*") do weekday "%%I" > "temp.txt" & set /p VAR=< temp.txt

temperature VAR
```

I also tried to extract the outputs to different text files but didn't find a way to input value from those text files to the 2nd program.

```
for %%I in ("*.*") do weekday "%%I" > "%%~nI.txt" & set /p VAR=< %%~nI.txt

temperature VAR
```

Say I want to extract day info of two files 1(Monday) and 2(Tuesday). Used the loop above I am able to extract Monday and Tuesday, and put them into different text files, respectively (1.txt and 2.txt). However, `temperature` only shows the result for Tuesday. While I expected `temperature` would run different loops for Monday and Tuesday. I tested it with echo and it also showed Tuesday only.

I would appreciate direction as to how I would pipe the outputs from `weekday` to `temperature`, one at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: have you run your script with `@echo on`? Your failure should be quite obvious (hint: where does your `for` loop end?)

Comment: You are talking about a pipe, but what you actually mean is an argument: `temperature day` (`day` is the argument), `echo day|temperature` would pipe `day` into _STDIN_ of `temperature`... Ah, and to read from a variable, enclose it in `%%`, like `%VAR%`...

Comment: What about this: `for %%F in ("*.*") do for /F %%W in ('weekday "%%~F"') do temperature %%I` (`for` loops over the files, `for /F` captures the output of `weekday`)

Comment: Thanks, guys!!! That worked like a charm! I didn't realize that my script is not a complete loop! Please write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the best answer.